# react-native-sqlite-storage database not connecting

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database

**It doesn't shows Database Connected or not**

**I am Using Expo**

```
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase({
    name: 'class_finder.db',
    location: 'default'
},
() => {
    console.log("Database connected!")
}, //on success
error => console.log("Database error", error) //on error
)


useEffect(() => {
                db.transaction(function (txn) {
                txn.executeSql(
                    "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_user'",
                    [],
                    function (tx, res) {
                    console.log('item:', res.rows.length);
                    if (res.rows.length == 0) {
                        txn.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_user', []);
                        txn.executeSql(
                        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_user(user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_name VARCHAR(20), user_contact INT(10), user_address VARCHAR(255))',
                        []
                        );
                    }
                    }
                );
                });
            }, []);
```

I have tried expo sqlite storage for Connection. But None of them Works. I have installed previous version also but couldnt get solution.

**If there is any other way to use sqlite  Please let me know**